# i want to display my item information in a dialog on click

Tags: android

I have this setup where i want to display the item details in a dialog when the item is clicked. I am using the code below but the dialog does not show up when the item is clicked and i get no errors.

```
public class ptaAdapters extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ptaAdapters.ptaViewHolder>
{
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<ptaModel> mDataList = Collections.emptyList();
    private Context context;

    public ptaAdapters(Context context, List<ptaModel> ptaList)
    {
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mDataList = ptaList;
        this.context = context;

    }
    @Override
    public ptaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pta_list_item,parent,false);

        ptaViewHolder holder = new ptaViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return mDataList.size();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ptaViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        final ptaModel current = mDataList.get(position);

        holder.date.setText(current.getDate());
        holder.minutes.setText(current.getContent());
        holder.title.setText(current.getTitle());

        holder.minutes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();

            builder.setTitle(current.getTitle());
            builder.setMessage(current.getContent());

            builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.pta_detail_view, null))
                .setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                    {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
 builder.create();
            }
        });
    }
    class ptaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView date,minutes,title;

        public ptaViewHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pta_date);
            minutes = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pta_minutes);
            title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.pta_title);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: WHat kind of type is the pta_detail_view ? You are trying to replace a textview with this...

Answer (score 1):

Call `builder.create().show()` after your call to `builder.setView()`. Your dialog wont display if you dont call `.show()`

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you only create the dialog but you didn't tell it to show.

Use `builder.create().show();`